# Avoid code duplication using interfaces as parameter

Tags: go, optimization, struct, interface

I have multiples structs with common relation on another struct

```
type Question struct {
    ID  int `json:"id,omitempty"`
    ...
}

type EvaluationQuestion struct {
    Question   Question `json:"question" sql:"-"`
    Min        int      `json:"min"`
    Max        int      `json:"max"`
    QuestionID int      `json:"question_id,omitempty"`
}

type TextQuestion struct {
    Question   Question `json:"question" sql:"-"`
    MaxValue   int      `json:"max_value"`
    QuestionID int      `json:"question_id,omitempty"`
}
```

I also have a method to save data inside my database that will be the same for every struct, only the struct type will change

```
func CreateTextQuestion(textQuestion *TextQuestion) error {
    question := textQuestion.Question

    if err := database.Db.Insert(&question); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    textQuestion.QuestionID = question.ID

    return database.Db.Insert(textQuestion)
}
```

To avoid code duplication I tried to use interface that will implement methods for each struct (even if the is some duplication too...)

```
type Entity interface {
    getQuestion() Question
    questionID(int) TextQuestion
}

func (t TextQuestion) getQuestion() Question {
    return t.Question
}

func (t TextQuestion) questionID(id int) TextQuestion {
    t.QuestionID = id

    return t
}

func (e EvaluationQuestion) getQuestion() Question {
    return e.Question
}

func (e EvaluationQuestion) questionID(id int) EvaluationQuestion {
    e.QuestionID = id

    return e
}
```

Then I updated my `Create` method to use this interface

```
func Create(entity Entity) error {
    question := entity.getQuestion()

    if err := database.Db.Insert(&question); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    questionType := entity.questionID(question.ID)

    return database.Db.Insert(&questionType)
}
```

The problem is that my interface is not compatible with each struct, so I get compilation errors because the expected return type of my `questionID` method is not the correct one

> api_1       | [00] handlers/choiceQuestion.go:28:39: cannot convert question (type models.ChoiceQuestion) to type models.Entity:
>   api_1       | [00]  models.ChoiceQuestion does not implement models.Entity (wrong type for models.questionID method)
>   api_1       | [00]      have models.questionID(int) models.ChoiceQuestion
>   api_1       | [00]      want models.questionID(int) models.TextQuestion

Is there a way to avoid code duplication when dealing with multiple structs with Go?

I also tried with type switch and reflection without success.

Comment: Use the same type for each interface function.

Comment: @Flimzy Ok I return an `interface{}` and this is working